# Pyinstaller - the exec outfile works just as expected. But the app output fails (but only on 1 item) without an error

Tags: pyinstaller, pysimplegui

This program is a feature rich GUI (thanks to PySimpleGUI) that formats and displays info.  Nothing too sophisticated.   Its on a Mac M1 - Big Sur.  My compile script below is pretty basic too.  One screen of my program has a handful of buttonmenus, and for one  item on one button, the app produced by pyinstaller exits the program. But the consul just says "process completed, exit code 0."  (means "no error")?    And that same item works fine - produces the expected output - if I run the corresponding exec file that pyinstaller produced.  (And of course, that item works fine when I run it from within my IDE (PyCharm).   So....not to sure where to look.  Ideas?

```py
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--onefile',
    '--clean',
    '-y',
    '--windowed',
    '--icon="zaad.icns"'
```

Comment: Maybe try using the psgcompiler to generate your binary file?  May not help since looks like you've got a good handle on the options, etc.  and may introduce more issues than solves.  Could be an OK option for after you get the options figured out though so that you don't have to write code to make the app.

Comment: I belatedly stumbled upon the PSG compiler - too late for this project. But that does seem like a great application,  and a cool addition to thr PySimpleGUI bag of tricks.  (I'm a big fan of PySimpleGUI - addicted to it, perhaps.)

Comment: BTW, I was a able to make this work.  But I'm not sure how exactly.  It seems to have something to do  with opening pdf or png files,    and whether they have 3 letter file type suffix or not      But it seems like the compiled exec can accept either (with or without), but the compiled app cannot.   Ie, it must have the suffix, else it fails (but doesn't seem to know it - exits with code 0.)  But  ... odd that they are different form each other.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Or maybe it runs code in different folder and it can't find some file. Or you have files with suffix and without suffix and exec works, but later you can run app in folder which has only files with suffix and then it can't work withut suffix. You could use `os.listdir()` to see files which you have in forlder(s)